Phonon dispersion and what wave it represents
To start things off, I'm doing a semestral project on phonons and I'm to find a dispersion relation of a crystal (with the use phonopy). I chose to do hexagonal boron nitride.
From my understanding, the wave vector on the x-axis is linked to the wave vector of the phonon mode waves, and that you have different types of modes depending on how the wave is propagating (TA, LA, TO, ZO, etc.).

Now, the question I have, is that I managed to find animations and pictures of specific phonon modes of hexagonal boron nitride, but I don't understand why the animation one is labeled TO and not LO. I circled the one I think it is in the picture of the dispersion relation of another article. I'm sure that idea is somehow wrong but I don't know why.


I circled the one I think it is (LO), but the label on the animation says it's TO and it's either wrong, or my understanding is wrong. Which one is it please guys?
